# Estimate Bluriness/Sharpness of Similar Images

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, blur

I have thousands of images shot for 3D reconstruction using photogrammetry and I want to evaluate which images are *too* blurry using Imagemagick or any other command line able software. What means *too* blury: based on the average blurriness/sharpness of all images, the worst images can be picked out easily. But how to evaluate the bluriness. I have gone into FFT, Fast Fournier Transform and think here can be found the solution. The frequencies can be calculated by the IM -fft command, which produces the magnitude and phases images. How can one use these images to calculate an overall bluriness/sharpness factor?

Update: Here are some of the images I have to treat. The real challenge is, all images are alongside many others of these kinds in a single folder and need to be checked for motion blur issues. I have to detect too high motion blur and avoid these images in further production.

Next 3 images have from all images the lowest deviation, but are very sharp in the original full-reso version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

These 2 images have a lower deviation because of the white areas, but also don't lack of enough sharpness.

[image]

[image]

Here the edge detection brings various edges, because of the mosaic. From all images the first image is blurry.

[image]

This image has low blurriness.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have an idea using ImageMagick. I take an original image as follows:

[image]

then I put it into Photoshop and blur it with Motion blur of 5 pixesl and 10 pixels, saving the results as `blur5.txt` and `blur10.txt`.

[image]
[image]

Now, I use ImageMagick to compare the statistics:

```
identify -verbose original.jpg > orig.txt
identify -verbose blur5.jpg    > blur5.txt
identify -verbose blur10.jpg   > blur10.txt
```

Then use `opendiff` (on Mac) to compare the statistics,

```
opendiff orig.txt blur5.txt
```

I note that the blurrier the image, the lower the standard deviation - so that seems to measure relative bluriness.

I then used a Canny Edge Detector, and you can see that the sharpest image gets the most edges, not unexpectedly. So, you could count the white pixels in the Canny Edge detected image as a measure of your sharpness.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Like this:

```
convert original.jpg -canny 0x1+10%+30% -format %c histogram:info:-
    875184: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
     72576: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF gray(255)          <--- sharp image has high white pixel count
convert blur5.jpg -canny 0x1+10%+30% -format %c histogram:info:-
    912322: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
     35438: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF gray(255)          <--- slightly blurry has lower white pixel count
convert blur10.jpg -canny 0x1+10%+30% -format %c histogram:info:-
    925759: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
     22001: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF gray(255)          <--- blurriest has lowest white pixel count
```

If you want a single line that calculates the number of white pixels and echoes the filename, you can do this:

```
convert original.jpg -canny 0x1+10%+30% -format "%[fx:mean*h*w] %f\n" info:
72576 original.jpg
```

That will allow you to analyse all your images and sort them into order of sharpness like this:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec convert "{}" -canny 0x1+10%+30% -format "%[fx:mean*h*w] %f\n" info: \; | sort
22001 blur10.jpg
35438 blur5.jpg
72576 original.jpg
```

Comment: Looks interesting, will try it on real data!

Comment: I tried both methods now on various of my images and the results are not very usefull. Thats because of the nature of the images, they are all interiors, but differ from their perspectives. Images are sometimes too different that the deviation is sometimes very high, but still the image can be blurry. Same for amount edge pixels, depending on the image this can lead to false assumptions. Both in combination won't work, if both can be false.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame :-( Can you post some real images so we can do some more representative experiments?

Comment: Now I can see your images it is obvious that the amount of detected edges is not going to work if you are comparing the edges in a mosaic with the edges of a general scene of a room! I understood, maybe mistakenly, that you had thousands of similar images of much the same thing but that some were blurry and some were not, and my method would tell you which ones were blurrier, but he images are not similar or comparable. Never mind!

Comment: @Markus did you find any solution for the problem?